Canonical trace on simple algebras
Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional simple $K$-algebra. The map $$T:A \to K; \ \ T(a)=tr(l_a),$$ where $\text{End}_K(A) \ni l_a:x \mapsto ax$ and $tr$ is the ordinary trace of linear operators, is called the canonical trace on $A$.
Suppose $A = \text{Mat}_n(K)$, then $tr(l_a)=ntr(a)$, and so $T(a)=ntr(a)$.
Now, I am wondering if we can extend this to the case where $A=\text{Mat}_n(D)$ for some division $K$-algebra $D$ as follows
$T(a)=n[D:K]tr(a)$?
How can we prove this? I am only checking the dimensions and come up with this formula. That is, $T(1_A)=[A:K]$, $ tr(1_A)=[A:D]=n$ and so
$$[A:K]=[A:D]^2[D:K]=n^2[D:K] \Rightarrow T(1_A)=n[D:K]tr(1_A)$$
Added later
I think I have found my answer, but I need help. I have seen in the book Quadratic and Hermitian Forms by Scharlau that $$T_{A/K}=tr_{L/K}T_{A/L},$$
where $L$ is the extension field of $K$ contained in the centre of $A$. So in my example, we can consider $L$ to be the centre of $D$. Then $A$ becomes simple $K$-algebra and central simple $L$-algebra. How can we proceed from this point? I am not familiar with the meaning of $tr_{L/K}$.
